# How to drop index by passing index name dynamically in my sql?

Tags: mysql

tried the below query but not working.

```
SET @index_name = (SELECT INDEX_NAME 
                   FROM information_schema.statistics 
                   WHERE table_schema = 'myDB' 
                     and table_name = 'test' 
                     and column_name = 'col1');
ALTER TABLE test DROP INDEX @index_name;
```

Comment: User variables, like `@index_name`, can't just go anywhere in the syntax. Is this the use case? Drop indexes of a specific column? Which MySQL version?

Comment: Also what happens if there is more than one index covering the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index name cannot be retrieved from the variable in the query. Use dynamic SQL, like

```sql
SELECT INDEX_NAME 
INTO @index_name
FROM information_schema.statistics 
WHERE table_schema = 'myDB' 
  and table_name = 'test' 
  and column_name = 'col1'
LIMIT 1;

SET @sql := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE myDB.test DROP INDEX ', @index_name);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```